# fp-ts pipeline with Option and chain not working

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have this sample code:

```
import {none, some, chain} from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable';

const f1 = (input: string) => {
    return some(input + " f1")
};
const f2 = (input: string) => {
    return some(input + "f2")
};
const f3 = (input: string) => {
    return none;
};
const f4 = (input: string) => {
    return some(input + "f4");
};

const result = pipe(
    f1,
    chain(f2),
    chain(f3),
    chain(f4),
)("X");

console.log("result", result);
```

And I am getting this compile time error

```
Argument of type '(input: string) => Option<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option<string>'.
  Type '(input: string) => Option<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'Some<string>': _tag, value

18     f1,
       ~~

  src/index.ts:18:5
    18     f1,
           ~~
    Did you mean to call this expression?
```

What is wrong with my code?

I expect `f1` and `f2` to run and other function not because of `none` returning in `f3` and at the end the output to be `Some "X f1 f2"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fp-ts [`pipe`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/pipeable.ts.html#pipe-function) function expects the initial value `"X"` as first argument to facilitate TypeScript left to right generic inference.

So in contrast to other fp-libraries, where the initial value is passed in a curried manner, you create the pipe as follows:

```
const result = pipe(
  "X", // here is initial argument
  f1,
  chain(f2),
  chain(f3),
  chain(f4)
); // type: Option<string>, actual value is None
```

The return value will be `None` - once an option is`None`, it will stay `None`, when you `chain` over it (implementation [here](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/60719ba83232660612208c4daaa61f8034470a5e/src/Option.ts#L635)):

```
chain((n: number) => some(n*2))(none) // stays None
```

---

Edit:

[`flow`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#flow-function) (equivalent of other libraries' `pipe`) is an alternative, that behaves in the way you want it in the example:

```
import { flow } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

const result3 = flow(
  f1,
  chain(f2),
  chain(f3),
  chain(f4)
)("X")
```

There may arise type problems. For example, it is necessary to have the function parameter types of the first function (`f1`) annotated with explicit types. Also consider, that `pipe` is seen as the new ["blessed way"](https://twitter.com/giuliocanti/status/1130885461340303362?lang=en) for compositions by the maintainers.

Comment: This would mean you can only create ad-hoc pipes that are immediately evaluated..

Comment: @bob added `flow` as alternative.